# Serving multiple Django projects in different virtualenv at the same IP (Apache)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to serve two Django projects on different virtualenv at the same IP adress on Apache.

My first site is at http://myip/site-1
and the seccond: http://myip/site-2

When I run http://myip/site-1, Apache serves it without issues, but when I run the second (http://myip/site-2) it raises the following:

```
The requested URL /site-2/ was not found on this server.
```

Because it searches in the first site's document root.

Here is my apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site-1.example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/venv/site-1

 # adjust the following line to match your Python path 
 WSGIDaemonProcess site-1.example.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/venv/lib/python2.7
 WSGIProcessGroup site-1.example.com
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/venv/site-1/site-1/wsgi.py

 <directory /home/venv/site-1>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /home/venv/site-1/static_root/

 <Directory /home/venv/site-1/static_root>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site-2.example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/venv_mob/site-2

  # adjust the following line to match your Python path 
  WSGIDaemonProcess site-2.example.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/venv_mob/lib/python2.7
  WSGIProcessGroup site-2.example.com
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/venv_mob/site-2/site-2/wsgi.py

<directory /home/venv_mob/site-2>
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
   Options FollowSymlinks
 </directory>

 Alias /static/ /home/venv_mob/site-2/static_root/

<Directory /home/venv_mob/site-2/static_root>
  AllowOverride all
  Require all granted
  Options FollowSymlinks
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried many solutions that I found on the web but the problem remains the same.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect to `http://site-1.example.com` (using terms from your example), not `http://myip/site-1`. And `http://site-2.example.com`, not `http://myip/site-2`.

Generally speaking you can have [name-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) for which you need to configure DNS (mapping `site-1.example.com` and `site-2.example.com` to your IP address) or you can [run different sites on different ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#port).

Comment: Thank you very much. I modified the apache.conf in order the second virtualhost to listen on 81 port and it worked !!